# What does the phrase "What’s it about coming from you" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Well, my English friend and me are just talking about a movie. So he asks me what I’m watching. So I tell him the name of the movie that I’m watching. It’s call “Sweet home”.  Then he texts me saying

> What’s it about coming from you

and I don’t understand it. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The idiom means: "What's it(the movie) about *according to you/from your perspective*?" - *What's your opinion about it/What do you think about it*?

for example

Person1: I don't know where you are coming from.

Person2: Well, I just thought that ...

Here are some resources:

[come from - idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/coming+from+you)